# Removing empty variable from array

Tags: php

I want to remove empty variable from array. I have explored different methods but couldn't be able to do this correctly. I have tried in the following ways:

```
$field1 = 6;

$field2 = 15;
$field3 = 7;
$demo = array($field1=>"info1", $field2=>"info2",$field3=>"field3"); 


 echo "$demo[$field3]";
```

If any of the variables (`$field1, $field2 or field3`) is zero the result should be Null.

Comment: *result should be Null* You mean when the key is 0 and you print that it should output NULL?

Comment: actually it seems none of your variables are empty so which one do you want to remove

Comment: $field1, $field2 all these are keys, so do you want something like this `$demo[0]` to be `Null`.

Comment: exactly. output will be null.

Comment: man.. your answers are so vague.. think about it.. will you know what to answer on your question?

Comment: the above code is working fine. If one of the variables is changed to "0". its output is not null.

Comment: SHOW US AN EXAMPLE of an occurance of this array that contains a value you want to output as NULL

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: I could not understand why the community marking my question in negative one. I would request them to think over it. However, I have got my answer. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$field1 = 6;
$field2 = 15;
$field3 = 7;
$demo = array($field1=>"info1", $field2=>"info2",$field3=>"field3"); 

$demo = isset($demo[0]) ? null : $demo;
echo "$demo[$field3]";
```

Comment: Oh! That is my code. It is working nicely. I really trying several hours for this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
 foreach($array as $key => $value){
     if($key == false || $key == 0){
         unset($array[$key]);
     }
 } 
?>
```

Do you mean that?
With that,  `echo "$demo[$field3]";` will output `NULL` if `$field3 == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

please try this way;

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($demo); $i++){
    if($demo[$i) == 0)$demo[$i]=NULL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code if the key of array is Null or 0. Item Delete from array.

```
<?php 
 foreach($array as $key => $value){
     if($key == false || $key == 0){
         unset($array[$key]);
     }
 } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
$field1 = 6;
    $field2 = 15;
    $field3 = 7;
    $demo = array($field1=>"info1", $field2=>"info2",$field3=>"field3"); 
    foreach($demo as $key=>$val){
        //echo $key."----------".$val; just to check
        if($key == '0'){
            $val='Null';
        }
    }
```